# c++ future call local variable

Tags: c++, concurrency, future

When using C++ future to call a function, if I define 2 future objects `a,b` and call the same function `foo`

```
 a = async(launch::async,foo);
 b = async(launch::async,foo);
```

is it the same as running the function twice?

```
foo()
foo()
```

i.e. are `a` and `b` each running their private copy of `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use the same function as this example shows.

```
void foo()
{
    static int counter=0;
    cout<<counter++<<endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
  std::future<void> resultA(async(launch::async,foo));
  resultA.get();

  std::future<void> resultB(async(launch::async,foo));
  resultB.get();

  return 0;
}
```

output:

0

1

This shows that the **same** static counter variable is used bcz the output is not 0,0 but 0,**1** (incremented as it goes into foo)

Hope that helps,

Comment: But that's because of the `static` keyword that retain the value of counter between function calls. In this sense, it's the same as running foo() twice directly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx

Comment: that's what I am saying at the begining of the answer "They use the same function as the example shows". What is missing for you to validate the answer?

Comment: I used a static member on purpose to show that it goes through the same code twice. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Yes. Without the `static` keyword the future call uses the function's private variable counter and will output 0,0. That's good.